# Bios sees HDD but doesn't want to boot on it

Tags: bios

So I removed Windows 8.1 from a friend's netbook, installed Linux Mint on it with a USB installation.
Now I am worried because the bios doesn't even try to boot on it, it just ignores it. Plus, there's is definitely something wrong because when I try to select "Path for boot option" (looked promising) it freezes on some kind of popup window... https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEgFk.jpg

I tried a lot of things, reseting config, changing almost every changes I could...

Also the bios can see it : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoF35.jpg
Also I can't open the netbook because of damaged screws.

What should I do to make it work ?

Thank you !

PS: Note that it works very well with something else than the internal HDD, an USB stick for instance.

Comment: When you say "the bios doesn't even try to boot on it" -- what, **exactly**, actually happens? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: I mean that I am used to see "No proper boot media on this device..." or something like that when the OS isn't properly installed on the hard drive.
Now, it goes straight to the BIOS because the list of boot device is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Problem "solved". Tired of this mess I backed up the data (since it was still possible to usb boot) and completely wiped the hard drive (it had two partitions) and reinstalled Linux Mint one last time. And it worked.
I don't feel very clever but apparently that's not the way to go when dealing with modern BIOS and Windows 8.